# How do I type an arc tangent in lua 5.4 if the math.atan2 is?

Tags: lua

I'm trying to use the math.library on Lua (version 5.4) and I tried to use the math.atan2 here:

```
math.randomseed (os.time())

local Player_x, Player_y = 400,300
local Enemy_x = math.random (0,800)
local Enemy_y = math.random (0,600)
local angle = math.atan2((Enemy_y - Player_y), (Enemy_x - Player_x))
local angle_degree = math.deg (angle)


print (Enemy_x..","..Enemy_y)
print ("The angle from Enemy to the Player: "..angle_degree.." degree.")
```

But when I tried to put run on my Visual Studio Code, it said that it was "discontinued" and deprecated. Is there a sort of way to fix this problem or is there a simple substitute of this situation?

Answer (score 5):

`math.atan2` was deprecated in Lua 5.3

https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#8.2

> The following functions were deprecated in the mathematical library:
> **atan2**, cosh, sinh, tanh, pow, frexp, and ldexp. You can replace
> math.pow(x,y) with x^y; **you can replace math.atan2 with math.atan,**
> **which now accepts one or two arguments**; ...

```
local angle = math.atan((Enemy_y - Player_y), (Enemy_x - Player_x))
```

Comment: @IanBoyd, see the answer/comment by user1542465

Answer (score 3):

> Be aware that math.atan is not a drop-in replacement for math.atan2. math.atan2(2,2) ==> 0.7859 vs math.atan(2,2) ==> 1.1071 Whatever the difference is: they're not the same. –
> Ian Boyd

For anyone running into this like me: Make sure you are actually using lua 5.3 or above. In 5.2 the second argument is simply ignored, so writing `math.atan(2, 2)` is equal to writing `math.atan(2)`, hence the difference.

Comment: Not sure why the last line claims that this is a comment rather than an answer. I'm not very familiar with Lua, but it at least *looks* like an answer to me.